# ios 8 MPMoviePlayerController in embedded mode, control bar has no progress bar

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

The following picture shows the problem:
[image]

The progress bar in the controls has gone in ios 8, but in ios 7, the progress bar is shown. Why?How can I enable it?

Comment: I am facing same issue with no luck

Comment: No still searching for the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Check **MPMovieControlStyle**.
and try to **increase** movie player view **width**.